# regular expression for tagging players in chat

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression pattern that can find all the players that a person has tagged in a message:

`/(?<=.*)(?<=[@])([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}(?=[ ].*)(?=.{2,})/`

@**benjamin** @**tyler** @**joe** @**nic** Hello!

And the following regular expression can select the entirety of the tagging text:

`/([@]([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}/`

**@benjamin @tyler @joe @nic** Hello! (includes space before "Hello!" and between tagged players)

However, I want a method to grab just the body of the message, such as:

@benjamin @tyler @joe @nic **Hello!**

What sort of pattern would I use to achieve this?

Comment: Actually taking the string and calling `.replace(regex, '')` might be the best option... even performance wise

Comment: Caution: Lookbehinds are not vastly implemented and adopted by browsers yet. Do not use them.

Comment: `(?<= .* )` variable width lookbehind. Supported only in Dot-Net (and is ignored). `(?<= [@] )` Lookbehind not supported in JS. `(?= [ ] .* )` useless extra verbage `.*`.  Here `(?= [ ] .* )(?= .{2,} )` reduces to `(?= [ ] .)` Result, useless regex in JS. Finally, `([@]([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}` better written as `(?:@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,16}[ ])+`

Comment: I think I am starting to understand regex better. So a whole string can be a "match"  but you can capture multiple "groups" and return them at request, making lookarounds not very necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
(?:[@](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}(.*)
```

If multiline is also included in the message:

```
(?:[@](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}((?:.|\s)*)
```

*Note*: these won't pull out usernames from the middle of the body

If you want to pull out all referenced usernames:

```
/(?:(@\w{1,16})\b){1,}/g
```

Yours at current will just pull out the last one.

**Edit**

In fact, using the last regex there:

```js
function getUsernamesAndBody(message) {
  let regex = /(?:(@\w{1,16})\b){1,}/g,
    info = {
      body: message,
      usernames: []
    }

  do {
    match = regex.exec(message);
    if (match) {
      info.usernames.push(match[1])
    }
  } while (match);

  info.usernames.forEach((username) => {
    info.body = info.body.replace(username, "").trim();
  });

  return info
}


let fullMessage = `@benjamin @tyler @joe @nic Hello! Hi @john
Hi Guys`;

console.log(getUsernamesAndBody(fullMessage))
```

It will add multiple of the same username to the array, but you can add a check in there if you wanted to only capture a single mention. This also means that if a username is mentioned in the middle of the body, you have captured that and removed it from the body (if that is not needed, then some rework can be done)

Comment: I noticed you keep using non-capturing parentheses, meaning you can't actually pull anything out.... :(

Comment: I use non capturing on a lot of it because the information within them has not been requested for capture, so why store data you will not need?

Comment: "However, I want a method to grab ... the body of the message" It *has* been requested.

Comment: And the body of the message is captured, the **usernames** are not

Comment: Wait... sorry, I didn't see your capturing parentheses around the non-capturing ones...

Comment: @Feathercrown Added example usage of my username capture

Comment: Ok you have me beat ;)

Comment: This works well. I noticed names attempted to be tagged in the middle of the message body were captured as both tagged usernames as well as part of the message. I am not even sure what the ideal behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

```
/([@]([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}(.+)/.exec(`@benjamin @tyler @joe @nic Hello!`)[matchingGroup]
```

where matching group in this case is 3, because it is your third set of parenthesis.

Comment: `(?:@[^\W_]{1,16} )+(.+)` is shorter.

Comment: Note that this doesn't match newlines. Combining this with Kyle's answer (which is what I was trying to do myself) yields the correct solution, which matches newlines as well as other characters, including @ symbols, while also returning the group and printing it rather than leaving it in non-capturing parentheses.

Comment: @Feathercrown pretty sure `.` matches any character. Why do you think it doesn't match @?... also OP can probably figure out how to add newline if they want it. Their messages may be stored without new lines for all we know...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works.

```js
console.log(/([@]([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}((.|\s)*)/.exec("@benjamin @tyler @joe @nic Hello\nnewlines work too! oi*)&) hjoi[JPOIJ(N#* Any character works yay! Even the @ symbol!")[3]);
```

Comment: Works well. Its a little cleaner if we make less of the groups as capturing (something I just learned about here. For example, `/(?:[@](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}[ ]){1,}((?:.|\s)*)/` will only capture the body of the message as a group.